# Docker command inside docker container

Tags: docker, jenkins, ansible, devops

I have a Ubuntu host. In this host, I run a docker container that gives me Jenkins app.

In the pipeline, Jenkins begin to clone git repositories.

Then inside Jenkins node, I run another docker container that needs as reference a file downloaded in the previous step.

Thing is when I connect manually into jenkins container I can see all those files, but when I run the second docker command, instead of seeing my files, it seems that I see the host fs...

Right now, I mount my volumes with ansible:

```
jenkins-slave-docker:
  image: "{{ registry_url }}/jenkins-slave-docker"
  restart: unless-stopped
  tty: true
  privileged: true
  stdin_open: true
  volumes:
    - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"
    - "/var/run/docker.sock:/etc/default"
```

How should I access the git files of the Jenkins container ?

Comment: If the code is cloned on the master jenkins instance, you need either to bind the code dir to the container via a volme, or copy the files inside the container using stash and unstash...

Comment: Code is cloned on maven node, I stash it, and unstash it on docker node, but I docker command is not finding the files

Answer (score 0):

you should just mount
-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock 
with that you should have just the docker socket of the host, that is what you need to run docker commands inside your container.

Comment: your container is running as root ?